# Problema com plugin de compartilhar do facebook

Tags: .net, facebook, plugin

Estou tendo um problema com o plugin de compartilhar do *facebook*. Ao clicar em compartilhar, percebam(1º print) que não aparece a imagem, agora se eu já tiver carregado ela em uma nova aba por exemplo, ela aparece(2º *print*).

Parece que a imagem só é mostrada quando esta em cache.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Alguma solução?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

As vezes isso ocorre porque a imagem a ser exibida ou é pesada ou quando o Facebook chama a url da imagem a mesma demora a responder/retornar. Já quando você faz a segunda tentativa ele já a tem. 
Verifica o tamanho da imagem e se quando você acessa a url direta dela o tempo de resposta está sendo rápido. Pode ser isso.

Obs.: Outra coisa que pode ajudar é se ela já estiver nos tamanhos predefinidos do Facebook: 1200x630, 600x315 ou menor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar isso bem definido no <head> da sua página com as [metas og](http://ogp.me/) ..

Exemplo do site [Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/utilizando-meta-tags-facebook/):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.meusite.com.br/imagem.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800"> /** PIXELS **/
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600"> /** PIXELS **/
```

Espero ter ajudado.